# How can I combine two time-series datasets with different time-steps?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, merge, dataset, lstm

I want to train a Multivariate LSTM model by using data from 2 datasets [MIMIC-1.0](https://physionet.org/content/mimicdb/1.0.0/) and [MIMIC-3](https://mimic.physionet.org/about/mimic/). The problem is that the vital signs recorded in the first data set is minute by minute while in MIMIC-III the data is recorded hourly. There is a interval difference between recording of data in both data sets.

I want to predict diagnosis from the vital signs by giving streams/sequences of vital signs to my model every 5 minutes. How can I merge both data sets for my model?

Comment: This is a very broad.  Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to find a common field using which you can do a merge. For e.g. patient_ids or it's like. You can do the same with ICU episode identifiers. It's a been a while since I've worked on the MIMIC dataset to recall exactly what those fields were.

Comment: I think the both data sets are of different patients and there are no common patient_ids.

Comment: Ok, got it. So the datasets belong to different patients. Do they share common variable names (vitals etc.)? If yes, you can merge the datasets based on the features you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

| Dataset | Granularity | Subsampling for 5-minutely |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MIMIC-I | Minutely | Subsample every 5th reading |
| MIMIC-III | Hourly | Interpolate the 10 5-minutely readings between each pair of consecutive hourly readings |

The interpolation method you choose to get the between hour readings could be as simple as forward-filling the last value. If the readings are more volatile, a [more complex method](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Visualization-of-the-feature-extraction-interpolation-techniques-from-the-raw-data-within_fig1_335939202) may be appropriate.